# wxToolBar with dropdown menu: no reaction on selected item

Tags: c++, events, wxwidgets

I'm using a wxToolBar which makes use of a drop-down menu with following code (simplified):

```
g_toolBar1->AddTool(TOOLBAR_CMD_CONTROL_DROPDOWN,_("Control elements"),MainWin::getBitmap(gearsXPM,"gears"),wxNullBitmap,wxITEM_DROPDOWN);
custParent->Connect(TOOLBAR_CMD_CONTROL_DROPDOWN,wxEVT_COMMAND_TOOL_CLICKED,wxCommandEventHandler(DrawCanvasSwitcher::OnToolbar),NULL,g_drawCanvas);

wxMenu *controlMenu=new wxMenu;

// following is repeated several times to have more than onw drop-down item
// (*it) is an iterator to an container holding the required data
wxMenuItem *item=new wxMenuItem(controlMenu,wxID_ANY,(*it)->m_entityParams.m_name,(*it)->m_entityParams.m_shorthelp);
controlMenu->Append(item);
item->SetBitmap(*(*it)->m_entityParams.m_bmToolbar);
item->SetId((*it)->m_wxID);
custParent->Connect(item->GetId(),wxEVT_COMMAND_TOOL_DROPDOWN_CLICKED,wxCommandEventHandler(DrawCanvasSwitcher::OnMenu),NULL,g_drawCanvas);

g_toolBar1->SetDropdownMenu(TOOLBAR_CMD_CONTROL_DROPDOWN,controlMenu);

g_toolBar1->Realize();
```

So the first Connect() is successful and when clicking the top toolbar item, I end up in DrawCanvasSwitcher::OnToolbar(). The second Connect() - which is simply copied from a different position in same file and where it works fine for normal menu items - does not work, I never get an event in DrawCanvasSwitcher::OnMenu() when selecting a toolbar drop-down item. The event type is the same as used in the toolbar-sample that comes with wxWidgets 3.1. g_drawCancas and custParent all are valid (and work for plain menu items).

So what could be the reason why I do not reveice events on clicked drop-down items?

Edit: using wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED instead of wxEVT_COMMAND_TOOL_DROPDOWN_CLICKED does not make any difference, still no event...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything obviously wrong in the code, so, as always, the best thing to do would be to try to simplify it as much as possible and/or try doing the same thing in the toolbar sample to see if you can reproduce the problem there.

One thing I'd try would be to specify `(*it)->m_wxID` immediately when creating the menu item, instead of setting it later. It *should* work as written, of course, but it's rather uncommon to do it like this, so perhaps there is a bug somewhere there.

If you do manage to reproduce the problem in the toolbar sample (e.g. just remove the event table entry for `MyFrame::OnToolDropdown()` there and use `Connect()` instead), please do [report it](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/newticket) as a bug, mentioning your platform.

And, finally, although it's completely unrelated to your problem, there is really no reason whatsoever to use `Connect()` instead of `Bind()` with wxWidgets 3.x, you should really switch to the latter for better compile-time safety and flexibility.

Comment: setting the ID via SetId() was the reason - when doing it on creating of the menu item it works smoothly - thanks! Connect() is used because this application also needs to be compiled on some platforms where I'm still at version 2.8...